# How does 7-zip check if the password you have provided is right?

Tags: cryptography, compression, 7zip

I'm trying to understand how exactly 7-zip recognizes if the password you have provided is correct.

For example I have a file x.7z that I have password protected with "password". Before I attempt opening it, the interface asks me for a password. How does 7zip check if this password is right before it attempts to unzip the file and fail?

Comment: Does it? Have you checked the response time as a function of file size? Generally OTOH most compression schemes have some remaining redundancy where the decoder faces an unexpected code before decoding the complete file (and failing at crc check). And more secure archives also encrypt the directory in order of not to reveal the file names.

Answer (score 3):

[It's encrypting the file using AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip#Features) with the password as the key. Generally these things will try to decrypt a block that it knows the value of (like a header that's the same for every 7z file), and then comparing the decrypted value with what it expects. If they don't match, it knows the password is incorrect.